# HTML radio button clickable label on mobile...weirdness

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I've actually got the click action going but when I do it on mobile, I get a bullet to the left and sort of up from the radio button (but only when I tap the label, it goes away after the label is tapped).

I can't figure out what could be causing this. Is it a known action when using this on mobile? It doesn't do it when using the same code for checkboxes so I can't figure out why it would do it for radio buttons.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code on jsFiddle (I've tried using just the "for" and using onclick which is why one label has it and the other doesn't):

http://jsfiddle.net/52uQP/

```
<input type="radio" name="contact" id="admissions">
<label for="admissions" onclick=""><span></span>Admissions</label>

<input type="radio" name="contact" id="cashiers_office">
<label for="cashiers_office"><span></span>Cashier's Office</label>
```

Thanks in advance.

Edited to clarify: This happens on iPhone 5 and iPad 2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when I do it on mobile?" On an iPhone, Android phone, tablet, etc?

Comment: Works fine on my android touch device on Chrome.

Comment: @sbeliv01: I'm experiencing this on iPad and iPhone using Chrome.

Comment: I sorta figured it out. I took it out of the unordered list, threw it in a fieldset and the bullet stopped showing. Still didn't figure out why the bullet is showing up but this works.